# Inputing data to different struct in a different class

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I already search in the internet, I still don't understand how to insert a value to a variable. im trying to insert a value to a variable so i can append it into an array and then put it inside a tableviewcell.

I understand how the cells works, i just wanted to know how can i insert a data to this variable

Here's the code for my struct

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum issueType: String {
 case major = "Major", blocker = "Blocker", minor = "Minor"
}

struct Issue {
var id: String
var tester: String
var type: issueType
var title: String
var appName: String
var desc: String
var date: Date
var bgColor: UIColor?

init(){
    id = ""
    tester = ""
    type = .minor
    title = ""
    appName = ""
    desc = ""
    date = Date()
    bgColor = UIColor.main()
}

init(item: [String:Any]){
    self.init()
    id = item["id"] as? String ?? ""
    tester = item["tester"] as? String ?? ""
    title = item["title"] as? String ?? ""
    appName = item["appName"] as? String ?? ""
    desc = item["desc"] as? String ?? ""

    if type == .major {
        bgColor = UIColor.main()
    }
    else if type == .blocker {
        bgColor = UIColor.blue
    }
    else {
        bgColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
}
```

Here's the code for the variable in the superDidLoad from different a class

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var issue1 = Issue(id: "id", tester: "tester", type: .minor, title: "title", appName: "appName", desc: "desc", date: Date())
    issue1.bgColor = UIColor.main()

    array.append(issue1)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UITableViewCell` subclass should have some variable of type `Issue`

```
class YourSubclass: UITableViewCell {

    var issue: Issue?
    ...
}
```

then in `cellForRowAt` TableView data source method assign cell's variable as element from `array` with index equal to `indexPath.row`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.issue = array[indexPath.row]
    ...
}
```

Comment: for the Issue type i already have this     var array: [Issue] = []

Comment: I got an error message of "Expression type 'Issue' is ambiguous without more context" in the var issue1 line.

Comment: @Nodoodle where did you get this message?

Answer (score 0):

After adding your own initializer to the struct you lost default memberwise initializer.
To avoid this use extension:

```
struct Issue {
    var id: String
    var tester: String
    var type: issueType
    var title: String
    var appName: String
    var desc: String
    var date: Date
    var bgColor: UIColor?
}

extension Issue {
    init(){
        id = ""
        tester = ""
        type = .minor
        title = ""
        appName = ""
        desc = ""
        date = Date()
        bgColor = UIColor.main()
    }

    init(item: [String:Any]){
        self.init()
        id = item["id"] as? String ?? ""
        tester = item["tester"] as? String ?? ""
        title = item["title"] as? String ?? ""
        appName = item["appName"] as? String ?? ""
        desc = item["desc"] as? String ?? ""

        if type == .major {
            bgColor = UIColor.main()
        }
        else if type == .blocker {
            bgColor = UIColor.blue
        }
        else {
            bgColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }
}
```

But even in this case you must to init all properties by default initializer including 'bgColor'.

```
var issue1 = Issue(id: "id", tester: "tester", type: .minor, title: "title", appName: "appName", desc: "desc", date: Date(), bgColor: nil)
```